# Node.Js + Now.js on windows: cannot load module node-proxy

Tags: windows, node.js

I am trying to create a chatclient for mobile devices using node.js and now.js. The problem is that the server must run on a windowsserver. Getting node.js working is not the problem.

The problem is now.js. I have already installed node.js and the modules: now.js and it's dependencies socket.io, socket.io-client. But socket.io still needs the module node-proxy. And that wont work on windows because it has to be build after installing.

Does anyone know how to get the module node-proxy for node.js working on windows? I have read something about building with cygwin but i dont have experience ( or knowledge) about cygwin.

Comment: Did you (try to) install now.js with `npm`? What happened?

Comment: There is a Windows build of Now.js available now. See: http://blog.nowjs.com/running-nowjs-natively-on-windows and
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nowjs/YHNjmtWKf98

Works fine on two Windows PC here.

Neville

Answer (score 1):

I'm coping the contents of the link nevf included in the comments to the question. I'm always scared links will go dead at some point.  Thanks to user george from source link for providing this solution that got me up and running.

> I just wrote a tutorial about getting it running under windows 7:
>   `http://nodegames.blogspot.com/2011/12/install-nowjs-in-windows.html`
>   Summation:
>
> Install nowjs in Windows
>
> First you have to go through the process of installing node.js in
>   windows. I have detailed the process here:
>   `http://nodegames.blogspot.com/2011/12/install-nodejs-in-windows.html`
>
> There's two requirements for nowjs to run on windows:
>
> Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime:
>
> Go ahead and install it if you don't already have it.
>
> `http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5555`
>
> socket.io:
>
> So we can open a CMD window and type:
>
> C:\progra~1\nodejs\npm install socket.io
>
> If your node.js install is in a different directory then change the
>   path accordingly.
>
> NPM will install it to:
>
> C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io
>
> Good.  Now we need to obtain the nowjs windows build here:
>
> https://github.com/Flotype/now/zipball/windows
>
> The file will read something like Flotype-now-0.7.6-3-gb41b2b2.zip
>
> Unzip it to a folder.  Inside that folder you'll have another folder
>   with a similar name.
>
> So:  ~\Downloads\Flotype-now-0.7.6-3-gb41b2b2\Flotype-now-b41b2b2
>
> Let's rename the second folder to now
>
> So: ~Downloads\Flotype-now-0.7.6-3-gb41b2b2\now
>
> Copy out the now folder and paste it to:
>
> C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
>
> So: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\now
>
> Inside of that now folder there should be subfolders like bin, doc,
>   examples and other items.
>
> You now have nowjs installed within windows as a module for node.js.
>   It looks like quite a bit of steps, but  in reality it is quite
>   painless and if you followed the steps you've seen that.
>
> Time to test it!
>
> The nowjs people have supplied us with three example projects:
>
> They are located in: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\now\examples
>   express_example helloworld_example multiroomchat_example
>
> Let's jump to the fun stuff and try and get multiroomchat_example
>   going.
>
> Firstly close down any node.js server CMD window instances you have
>   running.
>
> Open up a new CMD window and type:
>
> C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules
>   \now\examples\multiroomchat_example\multiroomchat_server.js
>
> Hit enter.
>
> You now have node.js running the multiroom chat example server.
>
> Take a look by pointing a few browsers to `http://localhost:8080/` it
>   will prompt you for a name.
>
> And if everything went perfectly you have now installed and tested
>   nowjs.
>
> A multi-room chat example in under 10 minutes, less than that if
>   you're quick!  From this point we have the ability to communicate in
>   real-time to multiple browsers and a server, the basis for a MMORPG.

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin stuff isn't supported anymore (afaik doesn't work anymore since 0.5.something). Also, there doesn't seem to be a good way to compile node modules on windows yet. I really think that you should try to find a way to run your node server on a linux box/vm if you really need nowjs.

But only nowjs needs node-proxy - socket.io doesn't and the RPC library dnode doesn't, too - they both work without native modules. I'd really recommend using dnode instead of nowjs anyway because its magic box is weird - for example, changes on the client side take up to 1 second until they get sent to the server (because the magic box gets polled for changes). Just use some clean RPC, like dnode, or just do message passing with plain socket.io.